# How to use this piece of code in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jQuery code:

```
var vis = (function(){
    var stateKey, eventKey, keys = {
        hidden: "visibilitychange",
        webkitHidden: "webkitvisibilitychange",
        mozHidden: "mozvisibilitychange",
        msHidden: "msvisibilitychange"
    };
    for (stateKey in keys) {
        if (stateKey in document) {
            eventKey = keys[stateKey];
            break;
        }
    }
    return function(c) {
        if (c) document.addEventListener(eventKey, c);
        return !document[stateKey];
    }
})();

vis(function(){
  document.title = vis() ? 'Visible' : 'Not visible';
});
```

What it does now is to change the document title of the page. If the page is not visible, it will be changed to that and vise verca.

My question is, how can I use this function like this:

```
if page is visible{
 //do something
}
if page is not visible{
 //do something else
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to call a function?

Comment: `if(vis()){ } else{ }`?

Comment: No. I'm asking how to use the function vis like described.

Comment: There doesn't actually seem to be any _jQuery_ in this question

Comment: what's going on with the first call to vis with an anonymous function?  That's... not going to do anything.  The bit about setting the title won't happen.

Comment: @numbers1311407: Note the `return function(c){}` inside `vis()`.  It sets `vis` to that function.

Comment: ugh my bad... I'm drunk apparently.

Comment: @numbers1311407 if `vis` is passed a parameter, it adds an event listener. If it's not passed a parameter, it just returns the visibility state.

Comment: @PaulS.: It returns the state either way :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `vis()` function is binding an event handler when it's passed one, otherwise returning the status. Thus:

```
vis(function(event) {   
  if ( vis() ) {
    // visible   
  } else { 
   // not visible  
  } 
});
```

Or more verbosely:

```
var handler = function(){ 
  // calling vis() with no arguments will return a boolean
  if (vis()) {
    // visible
  } else {
    // not visible
  }
}

// if a handler is passed, it gets bound to the event
// thus, runs on *any* visibility state change
vis(handler);
```